# Log4Net in MVC3 website only logs to SQL Database after stopping site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

I've got a MVC3 website that I've just started.  I'd like to add logging to this site, and decided to go with Log4Net.  I used this [tutorial](http://basquang.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/logging-using-log4net-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) for setting this up, and it works somewhat, but it isn't working as I expected.

I set up my logging per the instructions found on the site I was using for instructions.  I ran the site using the debugger and it should have logged a record when the Index action on the Home controller was called.

I checked the table and it was empty.  I stopped the debugger and checked my config file.  Everything looked OK.  I then put a break point on the line of code where the logging was done.  The code was hit, but still nothing in my log table.

I decided to turn on the log4net debugging.  I modified my web.config and started the debugger again.   Now when I checked my table, it showed two entries, but I noticed the time stamp was a few minutes old.

After additional testing, I found the logger was only flushing to my table when I modified the web.config file.

First of all, is this normal behavior?

If not, is there a way to get log4net to log without me stopping my website?

Thanks

**Update with solution**

Once the answer was provided by @tawman, I could then search on BufferSize.  This was the reason for the problem I encountered.

BufferSize is the number of Logs that will be queued before any are written.  I changed this value to 1 (as opposed to the 100 suggested - The default is 500).

This has my logs writing immediately. I don't know if there are any performance implications with a setting of 1, but I will have to look into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the buffer size to a smaller setting [log4net Config Examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
   <bufferSize value="100" />
...
```